# Sens du mot « dépendance » dans cette phrase

Tags: sens

Dans son *introduction à la philosophie de l'histoire* (1981),  Raymond Aron écrit page 273:

> En revanche, le principe de la sériation des dépendances joue un rôle essentiel.

Ici, le mot « dépendance » me semble étrange.

Qu'est-ce que la sériation des dépendances ?

Answer (score 1):

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%A9riation)) **Sériation**, subst. fém.
> **Action de sérier, classement en séries**.
>
> ♦ Le plaisir négatif de cesser de souffrir d'une dent que le froid irrite vaut-il la peine de renoncer au plaisir positif de prendre une boisson glacée par une chaude après-midi d'été?
> ♦ Le plaisir et la douleur ne font pas partie de la même sériation qui permettrait un classement homogène. Ils sont qualitativement autres (Ricœur, Philos. volonté, 1949, p. 105).− [seʀjasjɔ ̃]. − 1<sup>re</sup> attest. 1843 (Proudhon, op. cit., p. 137); de sérier, suff. -(at)ion*.
>
> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%A9rier)) **sérier**
> **Classer, ranger en séries**.
> ♦ Sérier des difficultés, des problèmes, des questions.
> ♦  Je me suis (...) si libéralement chargé de travaux jusqu'en juillet, qu'il sera sage de les dénombrer et de les sérier. (Du Bos, Journal, 1927, p. 181)
> ♦ Elle changea de métro dans un état d'égarement, horrifiée par ces dédales (...), ces portillons qui vous manœuvrent comme du bétail, comme si vous étiez un troupeau de porcs que sériaient des machines, dans une usine d'Amérique.  (Montherl., J. filles, 1936, p. 985)

Dans le contexte il doit y avoir une discussion qui établit l'existence de dépendances variées, ou de laquelle découle que des dépendances existent. La *sériation de ces dépendances* consiste à les classer selon divers critères, comme leur relative importance, le type de conséquence qu'elles impliquent, etc.

Une dépendance n'est dans le sens le plus général qu'une *relation de subordination (subordination et/ou soumission), ou de solidarité (physique et/ou morale), ou de causalité* ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9pendance)). Il faut trouver dans le contexte de quelles dépendance en particulier il est question.

Answer (score 1):

Raymond Aron décrit les principes de causalité.

Un fait est la conséquence d'une cause, il en est l'effet.

La sériation dont il est question ici consiste à expliquer les fluctuations économiques comme les cycles de croissance/décroissance, les variations de salaires ou de la production, de la masse monétaire, etc. par une suite d'événements de type cause à effet qui se succèdent, s'enchaînent les uns à la suite des autres.

**Dépendance** désigne ici la relation entre entre effets et causes, et **sériation** indique que l'on établit l'ordre chronologique de ces dépendances successives.

Aron fait référence aux travaux du sociologue [François Simiand](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Simiand), qui est l'un des premiers à avoir eu une approche très scientifique, en particulier par l'utilisations des outils statistiques, pour expliquer et modéliser les cycles économiques.